# How to limit the camera on a isometric 2D game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, linear-algebra, isometric

I'm developing a 2D isometric game just like Age of Empires 2, TTD, Into the Breach, and so on. I'm using Unity and C#

**Relevant fact: i'm using a Isometric Tilemap**

I want the camera limits to stay aligned with the borders of the map just like the games cited above but i'm having difficulty and i have spent so much time on this that i start to question myself if it's worth to use Isometric Tilemap or do the usual approach and just make a regular 2D game with the camera rotated.

And this is my first question: does Isometric Tilemap really worth or usual approach is better (non-isometric 2D game with rotated camera)? If so, how to do that in Unity?

Despite that,the code i've implemented follow below but it have two bugs:

- Camera get stuck on `firstBase` and `thirdBase` if the user press right/left key and up/down arow keys
- If the camera is moving on the border it may escape it

```
    void Start(){
        CameraMovement_Limits();
    }

    void CameraMovement_Limits(){
        Vector3 gridOrigin = tilemapFloor.GetCellCenterWorld(tilemapFloor.origin);
        float gridHypotenuse = ((tilemapFloor.size.x - 1) * tilemapFloor.cellSize.y);

        homePlate = gridOrigin + new Vector3(0, 0, -10);
        firstBase = gridOrigin + new Vector3(gridHypotenuse, gridHypotenuse/2, -10);
        secondBase = gridOrigin + new Vector3(0, gridHypotenuse, -10);
        thirdBase = gridOrigin + new Vector3(-gridHypotenuse, gridHypotenuse/2, -10);
    }

    void Update(){
        CameraDiagonalMovement();
    }

    bool CheckCameraPosition(Vector2 p1, Vector2 p2, Vector2 pos){
        //This is what this function do:
        //find the linear equation for the line formed by 'p1' and 'p2' coordinates
        //insert 'pos' coordinate on the equation and stores the result in 'ind'
        //if 'ind' is positive, it means that 'pos' is above the line
        //if its negative, its above
        //if its zero, its on the line
        //resuming, this funtion tells if 'pos' is above or below a line formet by 'p1' and 'p2'
        float a = (p1.y - p2.y) / (p1.x - p2.x);
        float ind = pos.y - p2.y - (a * (pos.x - p2.x));

        return ind >= 0;
    }

    void CameraDiagonalMovement(){
        Vector3 vecZero = Vector2.zero;
        camPos = (Vector2)transform.position;
        
        //Going to the left
        if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0){
            if(CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, thirdBase, camPos) && CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, firstBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            }else if(!CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, thirdBase, camPos) && CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, firstBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.x = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * .66f * -1;
                vecZero.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * .33f;
            }else if(CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, thirdBase, camPos) && !CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, firstBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.x = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * .66f;
                vecZero.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * .33f;
            }
        }

        //Going to the right
        if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0){
            if(!CheckCameraPosition(secondBase, thirdBase, camPos) && !CheckCameraPosition(firstBase, secondBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            }else if(CheckCameraPosition(secondBase, thirdBase, camPos) && !CheckCameraPosition(firstBase, secondBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.x = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * .66f;
                vecZero.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * .33f;
            }else if(!CheckCameraPosition(secondBase, thirdBase, camPos) && CheckCameraPosition(firstBase, secondBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.x = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * .66f * -1;
                vecZero.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * .33f;
            }
        }

        //Going down
        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0){
            if(CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, thirdBase, camPos) && !CheckCameraPosition(secondBase, thirdBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            }else if(!CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, thirdBase, camPos) && !CheckCameraPosition(secondBase, thirdBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * .66f;
                vecZero.y = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * .33f * -1;
            }else if(CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, thirdBase, camPos) && CheckCameraPosition(secondBase, thirdBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * .66f;
                vecZero.y = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * .33f;
            }
        }

        //Going up
        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0){
            if(CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, firstBase, camPos) && !CheckCameraPosition(firstBase, secondBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            }else if(CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, firstBase, camPos) && CheckCameraPosition(firstBase, secondBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * .66f;
                vecZero.y = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * .33f * -1;
            }else if(!CheckCameraPosition(homePlate, firstBase, camPos) && !CheckCameraPosition(firstBase, secondBase, camPos)){
                vecZero.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * .66f;
                vecZero.y = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * .33f;
            }
        }

        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(vecZero.x, vecZero.y, 0);
        transform.position += newPos * velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you get to exactly zero?  Going left is less than zero and going right is greater than zero.  If you are at zero the camera does not move.

Comment: In general for performance you should use `GetAxis("XY")` **once** at the beginning of `Update` and then re-use the result